# inner join wont work with mysqli prepared statement in php

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I can't seem to get this statement or statements alike to work with prepared queries, the code works just fine below:

```
$DBH = getDBH();
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT a.id, a.title, a.photo FROM tag t INNER JOIN tag_reference atx ON t.tag_id = atx.tag_id
        INNER JOIN articles a
            ON atx.article_id = a.id
    WHERE t.tag_name = 'example'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$photo);
    $stmt->fetch();
```

but when I change `t.tag_name = '?'` it gives me an error that the amount of parameters do not match. This is the statement that does not work.

```
$DBH = getDBH();
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT a.id, a.title, a.photo FROM tag t INNER JOIN tag_reference atx ON t.tag_id = atx.tag_id
        INNER JOIN articles a
            ON atx.article_id = a.id
    WHERE t.tag_name = '?'");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$example);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$title,$photo);
    $stmt->fetch();
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think it should be `t.tag_name = ?`, not `t.tag_name = '?'`.

Comment: I don't think you need the single quotes around the ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placeholder `?` does not work if enclosed in single quotes. In this case the SQL tokenizer will catch it as literal string.

Change it to:

```
     WHERE t.tag_name = ? ");
```

Comment: ah, thanks, simple fix, i thought i tried that but i guess i did not.

Comment: No need. And I just remembered it from last week where I tripped over the same thing. (Again.)

Answer (score 2):

When using placeholders, do you need to use quotes?  Most placeholder languages I've used don't.

```
WHERE t.tag_name = ?"
```

Comment: ah, thanks, simple fix, i thought i tried that but i guess i did not.