# Adding a loop to return individual rows that are grouped together in a SELECT query

Tags: sql, loops, group-by

I am using the following query to return rows grouped together:

`SELECT Work, COUNT(*) AS count, Amount, SUM(Amount) AS Total FROM work_times GROUP BY Work, Amount`

I would like to adapt this so that I can list the individual dates for each Grouping below data for the grouping.

So if I had the following table:

ID | Work | Amount | Date

1 | Therapy Session | £40 | 2013-02-02
2 | Consultancy Session | £50 | 2013-02-01
3 | Therapy Session | £20 | 2013-02-03
4 | Consultancy Session | £50 | 2013-02-08
5 | Consultancy Session | £50 | 2013-02-15
6 | Therapy Session | £40 | 2013-02-09
7 | Consultancy Session | £50 | 2013-02-22
8 | Therapy Session | £40 | 2013-02-16
9 | Therapy Session | £20 | 2013-02-10
10 | Consultancy Session | £50 | 2013-03-01

The query would be capable of returning:

5 consultancy sessions @ £50 each: £250

1st February 2013
8th February 2013
15th February 2013
22nd February 2013
1st March 2013

3 therapy sessions @ £40 each: £120

2nd February 2013
9th February 2013
16th February 2013

2 therapy sessions @ £20 each: £40

3rd February 2013
10th February 2013

Because I have grouped the rows together in the query, I am not sure how to then refer to individual rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is my minor modification of **JW**'s answer:

```
SELECT  b.*, c.date2
FROM    (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, 
                   COUNT(*) totalCount, 
                   SUM(Amount) totalAmount
            FROM tableName a
            GROUP BY a.work, a.amount
        ) b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%D %M %Y') date2,
                    date
            FROM tableName a
        ) c ON b.work = c.work and b.amount=c.amount
ORDER BY b.work, b.totalCount, c.date
```

I added **amount** to 1st sub-query, 2nd sub-query and the JOIN expression.

Hopefully, this link will work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ec1/24

Comment: Thanks, the output looks just right with your query.  I can't work out how to work with the results of an INNER JOIN query though.  With the original query I just used `$stmt->bind_result($work,$count,$amount,$total);` to bind the variables and then worked with these, but it would seem that I need to use a different method with the INNER JOIN query.  Would it be possible to add to your answer the correct way of returning the output I included in my question above?

Comment: @Nick

I'm not a PHP programmer but it seems that you will be doing it exactly the same way. You will be binding return of the main SELECT.

See if this helps any:  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399623/inner-join-wont-work-with-mysqli-prepared-statement-in-php>

Comment: Thanks.  I am getting closer - using `$stmt->bind_result($work,$amount,$count,$total_group,$date);` I can get all of the output, but when using `while ($stmt->fetch()) {` I am getting an entry for each row in the table, with the correct count for the group, but with the relevant rows not grouped together.

Comment: @Nick - Are you saying that you're losing the effect of **ORDER BY**? You also may want to add **PHP** tag to your question to attract the right crowd.

Comment: I asked a question about the PHP [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024249/passing-sql-variables-from-inner-join-sql-query-to-php-script) and the answer I got there helped me to solve the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  b.*, c.date2
FROM    (
            SELECT  a.work, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount, 
                    SUM(Amount) totalAmount
            FROM    tableName a
            GROUP   BY a.work, amount
        ) b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.work, DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%D %M %Y') date2,
                    date
            FROM    tableName a
        ) c ON b.work = c.work
ORDER   BY b.work, b.totalCount, c.date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ec1/8)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too familiar with SQLFiddle.  Having had a look though, it seems like your query is returning too many rows/dates for the therapy sessions (5 for each, instead of 3 and 2 respectively).

Comment: the query will not return as you desired because the result of every sql statement is a single array not multidimensional array. It's the job of your application to format the result.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Can you tell me how I bind the variables for such a query.  Is it the same as a regular query, i.e. for the above statement I would just create 5 variables?

Comment: @PM 77-1 That link isn't working correctly for me.  I am only seeing the schema

Comment: @Nick

Sorry about that. I'll post it as answer, notating that it's a minor change to JW's work.

Comment: OK, It would seem that I don't know how to work with the result of this INNER JOIN query.  Previously I just used `$stmt->bind_result($work,$count,$amount,$total);` and then worked with these variables.  It would seem that I need to use a different method for this query.  Would it be possible to add the method of returning the result in the format included above?

Answer (score 0):

2 queries and a UNION operator should provide the format you require.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ec1/27)

```
SELECT '' AS ID, Work, '' AS Date, Amount, SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY Work, Amount
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Work, Date, Amount, '' AS Total
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Work, Amount, Date;
```

Comment: Thanks.  As with the previous answer I am unsure about how to output the variables that I bind from the result of your query so that I can achieve the output in the question above.  I wonder if you could include this in your answer.  I am getting closer, but still I am some way off!