# Passing sql variables from INNER JOIN SQL query to PHP script

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

I have the following INNER JOIN query:

```
SELECT  b.*, c.date2
FROM    (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, 
                   COUNT(*) totalCount, 
                   SUM(Amount) totalAmount
            FROM work_times a WHERE Organisation=?
            GROUP BY a.work, a.amount
        ) b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT a.work, a.amount, DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%D %M %Y') date2,
                    date
            FROM work_times a
        ) c ON b.work = c.work and b.amount=c.amount
ORDER BY b.work, b.totalCount, c.date
```

You can see it in action on a sample table on SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0ec1/24).

My aim is to return the following:

```
5 consultancy sessions @ £50 each: £250

1st February 2013
8th February 2013
15th February 2013
22nd February 2013
1st March 2013

3 therapy sessions @ £40 each: £120

2nd February 2013
9th February 2013
16th February 2013

2 therapy sessions @ £20 each: £40

3rd February 2013
10th February 2013
```

But using the following PHP:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name1);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();  
$stmt->bind_result($work,$amount,$count,$total_group,$date);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        if ($count>1) {
           echo $count." ".$work."s @ &pound;".$amount." each<br><br>";
           echo date("jS F Y",strtotime($date))."<br><br>";
           $total_work=$total_work+$total_group;
        }
        else {
           echo $count." ".$work." @ &pound;".$amount."<br><br>";
           echo date("jS F Y",strtotime($date))."<br><br>";
           $total_work=$total_work+$total_group;
        }

        }
```

I am getting one line for each row, rather than the grouping, i.e.:

```
5 Consultancy Sessions @ £50.00

1st February 2013

5 Consultancy Sessions @ £50.00

8th February 2013

5 Consultancy Sessions @ £50.00

15th February 2013

...etc
```

And I am not sure how to amend my PHP to get the desired output.

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
5 Consultancy Sessions @ £50.00

1st February 2013

8th February 2013

15th February 2013

22nd February 2013

1st March 2013

2nd February 2013

9th February 2013

16th February 2013

3rd February 2013

10th February 2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the fact that you're calling the "head" for each row. Therefore, you should first check if it's been already called. I hope the following may help you:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name1);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();  
$stmt->bind_result($work,$amount,$count,$total_group,$date);

$last_work = "";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if($work != $last_work || $amount != $last_amount){
        if ($count>1) {
           echo "<br>".$count." ".$work."s @ &pound;".$amount." each<br><br>";

        }
        else {
           echo "<br>".$count." ".$work." @ &pound;".$amount."<br><br>";
        }
        $last_work = $work;
        $last_amount = $amount;
    }
    echo date("jS F Y",strtotime($date))."<br>";
    $total_work=$total_work+$total_group;
}
```

I moved the `echo date` and `$total_work` outside as they were being called equally in both cases (`$count >1` and `else`)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be along the right lines, but the output still isn't quite right - I am only getting one grouping returned as the $last_work variable stops any further groupings being added.

Comment: Well, in the case it's not the same it should add a new "head". Could I see the output to have a new try at the solution? :)

Comment: I have added the current output to the end of my question.

Comment: OK, I worked out the issue.  It was that, as in the case of 'Therapy Sessions' above, sometimes the work is the same but the amount is different, so I needed to add another variable `$last_amount` and then check against this as well, i.e. `if($work != $last_work OR $amount != $last_amount)`.  If you want to amend your answer I can mark it as correct.  Thanks

Comment: I amended the answer, but I'm still not sure if it's the correct one. I'll keep thinking about it :)
Btw, I changed the spacing so the output is similar to the one you were looking for.